# match columns in 2 tab-delimited text files

Tags: bash, perl

I have two tab-delimited .txt files

file1 has 20 million lines and the following structure

```
col1    col2    col3    col4    col5
1       x       x       A       x
2       y       y       A       x
3       z       z       A       x
4       x       x       B       x
5       x       y       B       x
6       x       y       E       x
7       x       z       F       x
```

file2 has 3000 lines and the following structure

```
col1
A
B
C
D
```

Now I want to extract from file1 the lines where there is a match between col1 from file2 and col4 of file1

So the new file3 should look like this

```
col1    col2    col3    col4    col5
1       x       x       A       x
2       y       y       A       x
3       z       z       A       x
4       x       x       B       x
5       x       y       B       x
```

How can I do this with perl or bash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use standard awk command to join 2 files:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} FNR == NR { a[$1]; next } $4 in a' file2 file1
```

Answer (score 0):

try this -

```
awk -F'[ ]+' 'NR==FNR {a[$1]++;next} $4 in a{print $0}' f2 f1
1       x       x       A       x
2       y       y       A       x
3       z       z       A       x
4       x       x       B       x
5       x       y       B       x
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you also asked about Perl, here's a reusable perl solution.  You first read file 2, generate an array of lookup values, and then read file 1, printing out any line in which column 4 matches a value inside of the array we created above.  Something like this might work:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my $key_file = shift;
open(my $fh, "<", $key_file);
my $header = <$fh>; # read the header line into '$h'
my %keys = map{ chomp; $_ => 1 }<$fh>;
close $fh;

my $query_file = shift;
open(my $q_fh, "<", $query_file);
print scalar <$q_fh>;
while (<$q_fh>) {
    my @fields = split;
    print if $keys{$fields[3]};
}
close $q_fh;
```

You can run this as `table_combine.pl <file2> <file1>`.

Comment: Better to use a hash: `my %keys = map { chomp; $_ => 1 } <$fh>` because then you can do `print if $keys{$fields[3]}`. Also, you could use `print scalar <$fh>` right after the second `open` to print the header. That way there is no need to check the line with a regex.

Comment: Very nice ideas, thank you!  Have edited based on your suggestions.